# How to make oracle accept the word "comment" as an attribute?

Tags: sql, oracle, attributes

## Problem

I am attempting to create an "examine" table with the columns `doctorID`, `admissionNum` and `comment`. The column `doctorID` references a primary key `ID` in the doctor table and the column `admissionNum` references the primary key `num` in the admission table. The following is my `CREATE` statement:

```
SQL> create table examine
2 (doctorID int references doctor(id),
3 admissionNum int references admission(num),
4 comment varchar(100),
5 unique (doctorID, admissionNum));
```

It returns this error about the comment line:

```
comment varchar(100),
*
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00904: :  invalid identifier
```

The problem is fixed if we change the word comment to something else, but for the sake of clarity, I want to include comment as an attribute, since it represents a doctor's comments after a visit.

## Question

How can I include the word "comment" as a column in an Oracle database table?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it in [ ]... [Comment]?

Comment: You have a typo on line 5 of your SQL statement: `docotrID` should be `doctorID`.

Comment: And on line 4 `verchar` should probably be `varchar`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tables don't have attributes, they have columns.

You can do this, I would suggest you think twice about it.

To do it, run

```
create table examine
 (doctorID int ,
 admissionNum int ,
 "COMMENT" varchar2(100),
 unique (doctorID, admissionNum));
```

Note I had to fix a couple of typos for you, you can't have a vercher or a varchar of length(00) - also you should use VARCHAR2 in Oracle.

When it's quoted, you can get around reserved words, but this will cause more problems than it solves. Instead consider renaming it to COMM, or COMMENTS, or a non-reserved word.

Comment: The typos mentioned have been fixed, and all references to attributes have been changed to columns.

Comment: If you do this, then every person from now to the point in which your application DIES, will have to quote that column in order to work with it, AND they'll have to match its case as defined. You might also consider making it a CLOB so users can leave an unlimited amount of text.

Comment: you can put an underscore in the end of the column name (e.g. COMMENT_ )